# Is there a way to make 3 cases on this code?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I made a discord bot and I asked for some help on this code on a discord server. They recommended asking here.

This is the original code

```
    if(msg.content.toLowerCase() === "yandev, buy something"){
    var Patreon = Math.random();
        if (Patreon > 0.5)
       {
             msg.channel.send('image link');
             msg.channel.send('Just bought this with my patreon money.');

       }
        else
        {
             msg.channel.send('image link');
             msg.channel.send('Just bought 3 of these with my patreon money.')
        }

})
```

Here is the code that I made with the help of discord people

```
    if(msg.content.toLowerCase() === "yandev, buy something"){
    var Patreon = Math.random();
        if (Patreon > 0.5)
       {
             msg.channel.send('image link');
             msg.channel.send('Just bought this with my patreon money.');

       }
        else
        {
             msg.channel.send('image link');
             msg.channel.send('Just bought 3 of these with my patreon money.')
        }
        else if
        {
             msg.channel.send('image link')
             msg.channel.send('Just bought this with my patreon money.')
        }
})
```

Both of these give the same error:

```
                else if
                ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'
```

```
                else
                ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'
```

I've tried to fix it myself, and cant find a way to do it.
So now I'm here. Thank you.

Comment: `else if` requires a condition and `else` should be defined after `else if` as it will only run when all the other conditions failed.

Comment: "if A is true, do B, otherwise do C, otherwise if D is true do E". Does this make sense to you?

Comment: See the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) for `if/else if/else` control statements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch your `else` and `else if` around. The order must always be `if -> else if -> else`. You're also missing a condition in your `else if`.

This makes sense since the last `else` will cover all conditions that you haven't explicitly checked for.

Answer (score 0):

What is the closing parenthesis on the bottom from?
From the code provided in the first block it should be.

```
   if(msg.content.toLowerCase() === "yandev, buy something"){
    var Patreon = Math.random();
        if (Patreon > 0.5)
       {
             msg.channel.send('image link');
             msg.channel.send('Just bought this with my patreon money.');

       }
        else
        {
             msg.channel.send('image link');
             msg.channel.send('Just bought 3 of these with my patreon money.')
        }

}
```

The second code block doesn't really make sense because your else if has no condition.

Try removing the ')' on the last line of the first block and see if it works.